# How to set absolute volume with -[NSSound setVolume:]? Not relative to system volume?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have an alert sound. I never want it to be "loud" and startling, so I'm reducing it via [NSSound setVolume] to an audible volume that's not loud.

But it seems as if the volume is set relative to the current system volume. So if I reduce it for the max-system-volume case, I can't hear it in the low-system-volume case.

If I use: `[sound setVolume:0.1];`

That sounds great when the system is set to full volume. But it's not audible at all if the system volume is at 1/3rd.

Basically I want to set a max volume for the sound. If the system volume is above that, it will play at my pre-set max volume. But if the system volume is below that, it degrades according to system volume.

Like this:

System = 1
-Sound = .3

System = .7
-Sound = .3

System = .3
-Sound = .3

System = .2
-Sound = .2

Is the only way to do this to manually check the system audio volume and set my sound accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An NSSound's volume corresponds to the volume slider you see in QuickTime Player, iTunes, etc. It's the volume for that specific sound, separate from and (as you've seen) subordinate to the system volume.

You can get the current system volume by querying the Audio Hardware API. Get the default sound output device, then get its volume. Then you can look into whether it's higher or lower than your desired volume level.

(It's worth noting that there isn't really one global “system volume”. There are two default output devices and any number of concrete output devices, and every one has its own volume. The “system volume” generally refers to the default output device's volume.)

Be aware, though, that this is not how any other application on the system works, so this behavior will seem unpredictable to the user. Expect bug reports along the lines of “the volume slider doesn't work when the system volume is above a certain level”.

Comment: I wont be playing a "real" audio track, just an alert sound, so it's hard to justify a volume slider in my app's interface. I've already gotten many bug reports along the lines of "the alert sound is too effing loud!" so I'm going to have to decrease it at the top volume. But that means you can't hear it at all at lower volumes, so I guess I'll have to do this variable volume thing.

Comment: Thinking about this more, what I'm going to do is base my sound off the system's "Alert volume" slider in System Prefs > Sound. Assuming I can access the value that is...

Comment: @cksubs: You can play the sound on the alert sound device and that will automatically respect that device's volume. And if it is an alert sound, using the System Sound API will automatically follow all of the user's settings regarding alert sounds.

Comment: Thanks. I found that playing my sound file via the AudioToolbox framework was the best/easiest option... it now respects alert volume and alert device.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect so (consider what happens if the user changes the system sound volume while your sound plays).

You may also want to make it user-settable. Expensive headphones are often very sensitive (i.e. loud); I suspect 0.1 is loud if the scale is linear.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to my exact original question, but where it lead: playing a sound file as a "system sound" that respects the user's "alert volume" and alert sound devices:

http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2011/05/23/snippet-playing-a-system-sound/

```
// Required import... Also need AudioToolbox.framework
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

// ivar 
SystemSoundID mBeep;

// Create the sound ID
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                     pathForResource:@"Beep" ofType:@"aiff"];
NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)url, &mBeep);

// Play the sound
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mBeep);

// Dispose of the sound
AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(mBeep);
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to set the system volume.  You can only set relative volume levels no matter how low level objective-c will allow you to go.  Even with coreaudio you can only set relative levels.

GW